# Swift: new methods in custom extension for SKPhysicsBody do not work anymore, throwing 'PKPhysicsBody unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

1. I have a custom extension for the SKPhysicsBody

   ```
   extension SKPhysicsBody {
       func hasCategory(_ searchedCategory: PhysicsCategory) -> Bool {
           let haystack = categoryBitMask
           let needle = searchedCategory.rawValue

           return haystack & needle == needle
       }

       func addCollisionWithCategory(_ category: PhysicsCategory) {
           collisionBitMask = collisionBitMask | category.rawValue
       }

       func addContactingWithCategory(_ category: PhysicsCategory) {
           contactTestBitMask = contactTestBitMask | category.rawValue
       }

       func removeContactingWithCategory(_ category: PhysicsCategory) {
           if contactTestBitMask & category.rawValue == category.rawValue {
               contactTestBitMask = contactTestBitMask ^ category.rawValue
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. It worked just fine. Yesterday I updated to the High Sierra OS, updated the project's PODs. After that I added a new method to the SKPhysicsBody extension and updated the project's code to use this new method in some places

   ```
       func resetBitmasks() {
           categoryBitMask = 0
           collisionBitMask = 0
           contactTestBitMask = 0
           fieldBitMask = 0
       }
   ```
3. Now, whenever I try to run the code on a device / simulator, I get the error

   ```
   -[PKPhysicsBody resetBitmasks]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb4d33176c0
   ```
4. The key problem is that

   - all previously existing methods of the extension - hasCategory(), addCollisionWithCategory(), ... etc work just fine, as they did before; I checked that by calling those methods right before resetBitmasks(); these previous methods still work also after being renamed
   - tried to rename resetBitmasks() to avoid probable name collisions - did not help
   - created a test method to the SKPhysicsBody extension, like: func lol() { 
     print("LOL") } and so this new method also triggered the unrecognized selector exception
   - reinstalled xCode, reinstalled PODs - nope, did not work
   - all other extensions I have in the project work just fine, no matter if I use 'previous' methods or the newly created
5. Summing all above, the problem only happens to SKPhysicsBody extension newly added methods. Saying 'newly added' I mean the methods that were added after the system (and xCode) update - still, I can not be sure this update itself caused the problem, as I did not add new methods to the SKPhysicsBody for a long time, so I had no chance to come across the problem.

Comment: In step 3) it says "PKPhysicsBody".  Typo?

Comment: @Dennis nope, it says exactly PKPhysicsBody (it's a copy-paste of the error). the thing is, AFAIK, SKPhysicsBody is a wrapper (?) over an internal (?) PKPhysicsBody class (I suppose PK == Physics Kit)

Comment: not sure if they'll help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492573/spritekit-weird-pkphysicsbody-crash and https://github.com/luisobo/Xcode-RuntimeHeaders/blob/master/PhysicsKit/PKPhysicsBody.h

Comment: @Confused thank you for the links; still, they don't help much, as the main problem is that the -'new'- methods added to the extension do not work, while the -'old'- ones do; hopefully I'll have some spare time the nearest weeks to dive deeper into the problem

Comment: Sorry I can't help more. @knight0fDragon might know more about this than anyone else.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code into a playground and it worked fine.  I was able to test a category, resetBitmasks, and then test again and see that that category was cleared.  Perhaps there is something specific to your project or environment causing you issues.  You might try the same experiment with a playground or a new project.

Comment: @Dennis well, I believe you're right - most probably, something might be wrong with the build settings. okay, will give it a try some nearest time. thank you for assistance.